# Reading error logs in Magento CE without access to the Administrative Panel

Tags: php, magento, nginx

Recently installed magento on an nginx web server. After sorting out a few issues with php5-fpm I managed to install magento. Every page now 404s (with the magento 404 template). I want to get to the root of the problem but magento isn't producing a system.log and nginx isn't bringing up any errors.

Magento seems to be writing to the /tmp/magento/var folder. The only subfolders of var are 'cache' and 'session' neither of which contains the useful 'system.log'.

I have looked around and cannot find a way of activating the log without having access to the control panel (every page 404's so I cannot access it).

Very annoying, considering the 404 problem is too generic to be tackled without a system log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues

1. If Magento is writing the cache to /tmp/magento then you have a serious file/folder permission issue that needs to be addressed from the SSH command line

   [Can't change Magento base URL, stuck in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940458/cant-change-magento-base-url-stuck-in-cache/8947825#8947825) - despite its name, addresses the issue
2. Changing the Magento logging from outside requires PHPMyAdmin or SSH mysql access to the database. The controls are found in the `core_config_data` table.

   Look for the path `dev/log/active` for however many scopes you're using and set to 1 (default scope if you've never set anything else up)

   Also make sure that `dev/log/exception_file` and `dev/log/file` are filled in with proper file names.

Comment: Just as an aside if someone cannot access their system.log I found that error logs can be read at <magento folder>/var/report

Comment: Yes, that's another log storage area which often contains the really show stopping Magento errors as randomly named files.