# Change Magento cache directory back from /tmp to Magento var folder

Tags: magento, caching

Magento has switched the cache directory to /tmp on the server for 1 of the sites on a Magento multisite installation. How do we get this to go back to the normal cache folder in the Magento folder.

Answer (score 0):

If this is multiple instances of Magento being installed on a single server, the usual reason for this happening is that the var/ directory has become non-writable to the web server process due to a change in permissions or ownership.

You will need to figure out what has changed either in web server/cPanel/WHM/suPHP configuration or if a backup or restore process has messed with file/directory permissions/ownership.

[Example of Magento cache being written to system /tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940458/cant-change-magento-base-url-stuck-in-cache/8947825#8947825)

Comment: Its actually only one instance of Magento running two websites, one of which is storing files in the tmp and the other in the default place.